# retype password verification not working

Tags: javascript

I used the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate() {
    if ((document.changepass.newpassword.value != '') &&
(document.changepass.retypenewpassword.value ==
document.changepass.newpassword.value)){
            document.changepass.retypenewpassword.blur();
            document.changepass.submit();

    }
}
</script>

<form name="changepass" method="POST" action="changepassword.jsp" onsubmit="return validate();">

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>New Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="newpassword" size="20"
            style="width: 145px" maxlength="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Retype New Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="retypenewpassword" size="20"
            style="width: 144px" maxlength="10"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Change Password" name="operation" ></td>
        <td><input type="reset"></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

but when I'm giving unmatched entry then also it getting changed.i mean the validate function is not getting called.
plz help

in hope 
robin

Comment: You'll need to format your code using the 101010 button. I'm guessing you ahve some HTML tags, which are being stripped out.

Comment: This is not relevant to the question, but you might be sure server-side code is providing the same control too. Javascript validation is easily skipped, and you can't rely on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onsubmit` handler on your `<form>` is looking for a return value, but is not given one from your `validate` function. Instead of calling `submit()` in the function, you should return true or false, depending on if the form validates (if the function returns `false`, that is equivalent to `onsubmit="false"`, which will cancel the submission):

```
function validate()
{
  if ((document.changepass.newpassword.value != '') && (document.changepass.retypenewpassword.value != document.changepass.newpassword.value))
  {
    // A password is given but it doesn't match
    // Perhaps you want to alert() an error message here to tell the user why the form doesn't validate?
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

Comment: if logic is wrong
`((document.changepass.newpassword.value == '')|| document.changepass.retypenewpassword.value != document.changepass.newpassword.value))`

Answer (score 3):

Your form will submit no matter what, because you are not returning false from the validating function on error. It should be:

```
function validate() {
    var d = document.changepass;
    if((d.newpassword.value != '') && (d.retypenewpassword.value == d.newpassword.value)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

At current, you are not specifying a return value for `validate()`, and it is interpreted as always returning true, so the form gets submitted. You don't need to call `submit()` from your function, simply return true if everything is ok.